# Retrieve results in array in jquery with semicolon

Tags: jquery

I would like to add comma or semicolon on the array result:

currently the output: {productproductnamedescription}

The output i would like to return: {product;productname;description}
or {product,productname, description}

code that i have so far:

```
var errorFields = [];
var arrayList = $("#form").validate().invalid; 
$.each(arrayList, function (key, value) {
        errorFields += key;
});
```

Comment: errorFields is an array, if you want to add an item to an array, use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). This question is a pure javascript question, not a jQuery one.

Comment: change  `errorFields += key;`  to  `errorFields[] = key;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.push()`

```
$.each(arrayList, function (key, value) {
   errorFields.push({key:value});
});
```